# CallableStatement PL/SQL is not inserting to database in jsp

Tags: oracle, jsp, tomcat, plsql

I am building a web with tomcat 8.5. And am using oracle for Db. I have wrote a procedure with PL/SQL named applyInsert04 like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE applyInsert04(cid IN VARCHAR2, cidno IN NUMBER,sid IN VARCHAR2,aid IN VARCHAR2, weeknum IN VARCHAR2,pstatus IN VARCHAR2 ,isprocessed IN VARCHAR2, result OUT VARCHAR2)

IS
nCnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
result:='';

INSERT INTO processed(c_id , c_id_no, s_id,a_id,week_num,p_status,is_processed) values(cid , cidno, sid, aid,weeknum,pstatus,isprocessed);
COMMIT;
result:='done';

END;
/
```

This was created with no error. 
And I used callable Statement to use this procedure with jsp.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String s_id = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
    String c_id = request.getParameter("c_id");
    int c_id_no = 3;
    String week_num = request.getParameter("week_num");
    String p_status = request.getParameter("p_status");
    String is_processed="unprocessed ";
    String a_id="01";


    Connection myConn = null;
    String result = null;
    String dburl = "url";
    String user = "suer"; 
    String passwd = "pwd";
    String dbdriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

    try {
        Class.forName(dbdriver);
        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, passwd);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    CallableStatement cstmt = myConn.prepareCall("{call applyInsert04(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
    cstmt.setString(1,c_id);
    cstmt.setInt(2,c_id_no);
    cstmt.setString(3,s_id);
    cstmt.setString(4,a_id);
    cstmt.setString(5,week_num);
    cstmt.setString(6,p_status);
    cstmt.setString(7,is_processed);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

    System.out.println(c_id+ "," + c_id_no + "," + s_id + "," + a_id +","+ week_num +","+ p_status +","+ is_processed +","+ java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    try {

        cstmt.execute();
        result = cstmt.getString(8);
        System.out.println(result);
%>

<script>    
alert("<%=result%> ");
    location.href = "apply_project.jsp";
</script>
<%
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (cstmt != null)
            try {
                myConn.commit();
                cstmt.close();
                myConn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {

            }
    }
%>
```

The file works , but it doesn't show the script which I think means that cstmt.execute() didn't work right. 
Please help me figureout what i have done.

Comment: Just an advice: do not use print outs, use log4j

Comment: you should not have that code in a JSP (rather in a Servlet) and you should use a proper connection pool rather than opening and closing connections for every requestn

Comment: the JSP doesn't show what you are expecting, but is the DB updated ? Did you check directly on the DB if it was inserted ?

Comment: The DB wasn't updated. So Is the problem with jsp?

Comment: Did you check all Tomcat logs ? You should at least find your `System.out` output, and the Exception logged through you `System.err` call, if any.

Comment: Thank you!! By checking the tomcat log I found out that I had a problem in the size of data types and the value that I wanted to insert.