# Inserting data from jsp to oracle doesn't work

Tags: oracle, jsp, tomcat, plsql

I am trying to build a web application with oracle connected to it. 
I wrote a jsp file code to insert data into database but it doesn't work. 
I want to use callableStatement and PL/SQL procedure that i have written down below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE applyInsert04(cid IN VARCHAR2, cidno IN NUMBER,sid IN VARCHAR2,aid IN VARCHAR2, weeknum IN VARCHAR2,pstatus IN VARCHAR2 ,isprocessed IN VARCHAR2, result OUT VARCHAR2)

IS
nCnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
result:='';

 INSERT INTO processed(c_id , c_id_no, s_id,a_id,week_num,p_status,is_processed) values(cid , cidno, sid, aid,weeknum,pstatus,isprocessed);
COMMIT;
result:='done';

END;
/
```

And this is the jsp file .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
< !DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String s_id = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
String c_id = request.getParameter("c_id");
int c_id_no = 3;
String week_num = request.getParameter("week_num");
String p_status = request.getParameter("p_status");
String is_processed="unprocessed ";
String a_id="01";


Connection myConn = null;
String result = null;
String dburl = "someurl";
String user = "user"; 
String passwd = "pass";
String dbdriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

try {
    Class.forName(dbdriver);
    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, passwd);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
}

CallableStatement cstmt = myConn.prepareCall("{call applyInsert04(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
cstmt.setString(1,c_id);
cstmt.setInt(2,c_id_no);
cstmt.setString(3,s_id);
cstmt.setString(4,a_id);
cstmt.setString(5,week_num);
cstmt.setString(6,p_status);
cstmt.setString(7,is_processed);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

System.out.println(c_id+ "," + c_id_no + "," + s_id + "," + a_id +","+ week_num +","+ p_status +","+ is_processed +","+ java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
try {

    cstmt.execute();
    result = cstmt.getString(8);
    System.out.println(result);
 %>

<script>    
alert("<%=result%> ");
location.href = "apply_project.jsp";
</script>
<%
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (cstmt != null)
        try {
               myConn.commit();
               cstmt.close();
               myConn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }
    }
    %>
```

Please help me out if I have done something wrong.

Comment: You already asked it before: [CallableStatement PL/SQL is not inserting to database in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254244/callablestatement-pl-sql-is-not-inserting-to-database-in-jsp) or is that a new question?

Comment: I was desperate to solve the problem but I couldn't so..

Comment: Put at least `ex.printStackTrace();` into the last `catch` block - otherwise you don't know if there was an error in `myConn.commit();`. Btw. such code does not belong to JSP, learn about the [Model-View-Controller](https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp) pattern, put the code to servlet, and use JSP only to display the result.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to learn more about it